# codeigniter join with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am just working out how do joins, and have made some progress. However after much searching and following examples online, I still cant figure out how to do a join on a condition. What I am trying to do is

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->select(
  'comments.commentType,
   comments.id'
);
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
// now if a commentType from the selection option above meets a certain 
//criteria ie commentType = answersAuthor join the below line.
// ie if(commentType = answersAuthor) etc {I know this doesnt work, but 
//trying to point out the logic
$this->db->join('authors', 'authors.id = comments.author_id');
```

So my results will have a few extra options in the result where the commentType answers the author.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: No one can help you with this without your db structure.  You have two select statements.

Comment: The first select is for blogs, the second select is for what to join query from comments. This code works. Can you not extrapolate the db structure from the example?.

Comment: did you try `$this->db->join('comments', "comments.id = blogs.id and commentType = 'answersAuthor'");` ?